# Vue JS and Video JS "ID supplied is not valid" error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, video-streaming, video.js

I have a basic project with **vue.js running and laravel** but I need to **play HLS videos on all browsers**, so after looking I decided to use **video-js**.

I have installed the video-player via npm succefully and tried to copy the following guide: https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-vue.html

But I keep getting the following console error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: The element or ID
>   supplied is not valid. (videojs)"

**Why will this not work for me?**

I have uploaded my code to github:
https://github.com/samB67/VueVideoJS/blob/master/VideosView.vue

**Mp4 videos work but not HLS videos**

Comment: Do you write the correct `ref="videoPlayer"` on your template?

Comment: Yes, I checked that first and can confirm all is spelled correctly!

Comment: I have uploaded my vue component to github @ the following: https://github.com/samB67/VueVideoJS/blob/master/VideosView.vue

Answer (score 2):

`<video-js>` is not a component. Use video html tag and ref instead.

```
<video ref="Player" class="vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
```

on script section:

```
mounted() {
   videojs(this.$refs.Player);
}
```

Comment: Thats great it works for mp4 videos but not for HLS video types. Do I need to include anything else for HLS videos? I have updated Github to reflect my changes, thanks (https://github.com/samB67/VueVideoJS/blob/master/VideosView.vue)

Answer (score 0):

For HLS videos
Try to add type="application/x-mpegURL" as an attribute

Something like this: <source src="http://myurl/api/video/playlist/zfJb3Hbs5FyZKCj.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" crossorigin="use-credentials"